# How to start python BaseHttpserver in AWS EC2 ubuntu instance

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I've the below HttpServer code working fine on my local ubuntu PC. but when i try to run this code in aws ec2 ubuntu vm, the server doesn't start. How can i achieve the below functionality in ec2 ubuntu? Any  help/info would be really great

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import cgi
import os
import time
class PostHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

def SaveFile(self,file_data, fname, dirname):
    directory = '/home/user/Documents/TS/logs/'
    directory = directory + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
    localfname = directory+'/'+fname
    with open(localfname,'wb') as f:
            f.write(file_data)

def do_POST(self):
    # Parse the form data posted
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(
        fp=self.rfile,
        headers=self.headers,
        environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                 'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
                 })

    # Begin the response
    self.send_response(200)
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write('Client: %s\n' % str(self.client_address))
    self.wfile.write('User-agent: %s\n' % str(self.headers['user-agent']))
    self.wfile.write('Path: %s\n' % self.path)
    self.wfile.write('Form data:\n')

    # Echo back information about what was posted in the form
    for field in form.keys():
        field_item = form[field]
        if field_item.filename:
            # The field contains an uploaded file

            fname = form['filename'].value
            dirname = form['dirname'].value
            file_data = field_item.file.read()

            self.SaveFile(file_data, fname, dirname)
            file_len = len(file_data)
            del file_data
            self.wfile.write('\tUploaded %s as "%s" (%d bytes)\n' % \
                    (field, field_item.filename, file_len))
        else:
            # Regular form value
            self.wfile.write('\t%s=%s\n' % (field, form[field].value))
    return
if __name__ == '__main__':
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
server = HTTPServer(('locahost', 8080), PostHandler)
```

Comment: If you post the output of your traceback, that would help.